# How do I pivot data (from long to wide), sum by ID, while merging duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data in long form. I would like to

1. Pivot it to wide (separate the "Year" column into individual columns for 2017, 2018 and 2019)
2. Exclude the "Category" column
3. Merge any duplicates. Please see screenshot.

I have used the code below to pivot the data. Note the table name is "data":

```
select * from Data
pivot
(sum(Dollars) for year in ([2017], [2018], [2019]))
as pvt_tab
```

However I'm not sure how to merge the duplicates (notice Wilmington highlighted in screenshot). Can anyone offer any suggestions. Thanks in advance. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to "FEED" your pivot with only the required columns

**Example**

```
select * 
 from  ( Select ID
               ,City
               ,State
               ,Year
               ,Dollars
          From  YourTable
       ) src
 pivot (sum(Dollars) for year in ([2017], [2018], [2019])) pvt
```